# function not updating data after every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

Function is not updating the latest data after every 10 seconds, even when I have set time out of 10 seconds (10000 milliseconds)

```
$(window).load(function(){
   setTimeout(function() {
   jQuery.support.cors = true;
   $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: {
         format: 'json'
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
},
      dataType: 'json',
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function(data) {
         var sensorsData = data.arduino;
         renderHTML(sensorsData);
      },

      type: 'GET'
   });
}, 10000);
});
```

See [live](http://www.devilsan.com/arduino.html) data

```
function renderHTML(data)
{
   var sensorDataContainer = document.getElementById("displaySensorData");
   var htmlString = "<table style='width:100%'><tr><th>Location</th><th>Temperature</th><th>Humidity</th></tr>";
   for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      htmlString += "<tr align='center'><td>"+ data[i].location + "</td><td>" + data[i].temperatureInC + "&deg;C/ " + data[i].temperatureInF + "&deg;F </td> <td> " + data[i].humidity + "%</td></tr>";
   }
   htmlString += "</table>"
   sensorDataContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
}
```

Although the google gauge I have placed gets updated .
what am i missing ?

Comment: i think it should be setInterval :)

Comment: Please read the documentation on `setTimeout`, and you'll see that it does not repeat. `setInterval` does, however.

Comment: @Kroltan just because I am renderingHTML from the same function after each interval it is rendering the table again and again , instead of refreshing it. [I have updated the code in the post above ]

Comment: Then you need to explain what *"refresh"* means in your situation. In other words provide a proper explanation

Comment: @charlietfl I mean to update the values in the table

Comment: You are using wrong insertion method . Add table element once and replace it's html each time

Comment: can you show me the right method please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

change this line:

```
sensorDataContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
```

To this:

```
sensorDataContainer.innerHTML = htmlString;
```

---

Change `setTimeout` to `setInterval`

Timeout occurs once after the given time, Interval occurs every given time..

Comment: just because I am using renderHTML from within the same function if I change it to setInterval it keeps on rendering the HTML table again and again , after every 10 seconds.

Comment: I feel its a totally messed up situation , so I need to pull json after every 10 seconds , but on success the renderHTML executes again.

Comment: So why do you render each 10 seconds if you dont want it to render? I'm not sure what exactly  you are trying to accomplish

Comment: If you want to refresh data, that's what you're currently doing so whats the problem? Do you want to append data or change it?

Comment: OMG, newbie in javascript you saved my life I want to hug you

Comment: however I am looking forward to learn Model view programming in javascript now.